# styled-components for input type password

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

how can I give styles for input type='password' in styled-components?

```
// export const Input = styled.input`
//   width: 100%;
//   height: 50px;
//   border-radius: 4px;
//   background-color: rgba(104, 105, 102, 0.1);
//   border: 1px solid #354545;
//   margin-top: 20px;
//   outline: none;
//   padding-left: 40px;
//   color: white;
//   font-size: 22px;
// `;
```

Comment: sorry input type='password'

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Unlike normal css, styled-components takes the attribute as `props`. You'll need to use props to style the elements conditionally.

```
export const Input = styled.input`
    ${props =>   props.type === 'password' && `
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: rgba(104, 105, 102, 0.1);
        border: 1px solid #354545;
        margin-top: 20px;
        outline: none;
        padding-left: 40px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 22px;
    `}
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

From styled-components [documentation FAQ](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs):

```
export const PasswordInput = styled.input.attrs(props => ({
  // Every <PasswordInput /> should be type="password"
  type: "password"
}))`
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(104, 105, 102, 0.1);
    border: 1px solid #354545;
    margin-top: 20px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 40px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both examples are a bit overkill for just styling purposes and can be easily avoided by using `&[type="password"]`

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Input = styled.input`
  &[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: red;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <Input id="username" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <Input type="password" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or, if you want to extend of of a base input component

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Input = styled.input`
  border: 1px solid black;
`;

export const PasswordInput = styled(Input)`
  &[type="password"] {
    background: red;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <Input id="username" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <PasswordInput type="password" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```